# How to write functions to add new column in a dataframe and based out of the value from the exisiting columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I write functions to add new column in a dataframe and based out of the value from the exisiting columns:

```
Request number      ReceivedDate                ClosedDate
1               2012-1-2                Nan
1               2012-1-2                2014-1-5
2               2013-1-4                Nan
2               2013-1-4                2016-1-5
```

Problem im having here is there are some request that are taking several years to complete and total days taken is in thousand and skewing the data. I wanted to distribute 365 days to the year not completed. Here I want to add a new column with the value if closeddate is not null then take the value from it otherwise assign the value of last day of the year. Also what would be better way to demonstrate the distribution of cases received dates of the closed ones?

Comment: Could you add example output? I assume you want to add on 365 from todays date but unsure

Answer (score 0):

You can `fillna` with `pd.offsets.YearEnd`. But remember to convert to datetime type:

```
# convert dates to datetime type
df.ReceivedDate = pd.to_datetime(df.ReceivedDate)
df.ClosedDate = pd.to_datetime(df.ClosedDate, errors='coerce')

df['ClosedDate'] = df.ClosedDate.fillna(df.ReceivedDate + pd.offsets.YearEnd())
```

Output:

```
   Request number ReceivedDate ClosedDate
0               1   2012-01-02 2012-12-31
1               1   2012-01-02 2014-01-05
2               2   2013-01-04 2013-12-31
3               2   2013-01-04 2016-01-05
```

Comment: Thankyou that helped. Now im in the following state: